# Share wlan with proxy server (MITM) test

Tags: linux, proxy, squid

I want to try stealing website accounts just for educational purpose. My idea is that I have laptop which is connected to the internet, laptop should share open wifi connection. If someone connects to my shared wifi he can access internet normally, but specific sites are guided to my localhost. For example if user types google.com it goes to localhost/google.com which is my fake google site, but the user sees address correctly. Is it possible to create this kind of shared wifi and how ? I was thinking if it is possible to do with Squid proxy etc. ?

Comment: I dont think this is a good idea. If its realy for educational purpose you should consilder building a test network with normal LAN connection.

Comment: I would like to show people how easily open wlan environments can steal their passwords. But yeah maybe I can use lan connection first and then expand it to wlan. Anyway if someone knows if this is somehow possible I would like to know thanks.